# What are your plans for the Annular Solar Eclipse on October 14th, 2023?

Tags: discussion, eclipse

On October 14, there will be an annular solar eclipse viewable from the Western Hemisphere. In an annular solar eclipse, the moon appears slightly smaller than the sun. At maximum obscuration, we should be able to observe a "fiery doughnut." **Observing directly with the naked eye or a telescope will cause eye damage.**

I plan to be rafting on the Green River, a touch North of ideal viewing conditions. Instead of observing the eclipse, I plan to observe the effect of the eclipse on the local wildlife. Do you have plans to enjoy/observe the eclipse?

More information from NASA: https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/eclipses/2023/oct-14-annular/where-when/ . The graphic is from the same page:
[image]

Safe viewing recommendations: https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/eclipses/2023/oct-14-annular/safety/

Comment: The International Balloon Fiesta in Albuquerque will host an eclipse 'balloon glow' event: https://balloonfiesta.com/Post/2023-Albuquerque-International-Balloon-Fiesta-Prime-Location-to-view-Annular-Solar-Eclipse

Comment: There's a John Dewey conference at SIUC in Illinois that I already registered to attend that whole weekend. So, looks like I can get a partial view during the morning! Wonder how many presentations that morning will have empty rooms . . .

Comment: I saw the total eclipse of 1999.  See it if you can, it's quite a sight.

Answer (score 4):

It will be partial for me. I will use this inexpensive apparatus.
I recommend a hole about the same diameter as the expected Sun image.

| Lens diopter | Focal length | Image size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| +1.5 | 67 cm | 6.2 mm |
| +1.25 | 80 cm | 7.4 mm |
| +1.0 | 100 cm | 9.3 mm |

[image: reading glasses taped to a 30 cm cardboard disc with a 7 mm hole, and the Sun image they project]